PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead
How do I resolve the following issue?:
"PyPDF2.errors.DeprecationError: PdfFileReader is deprecated and was removed in PyPDF2 3.0.0. Use PdfReader instead."
Used the below code and am getting an error msg:
import pyttsx3
import PyPDF2
material = open('Object_Oriented_Programming_Python_Tutorial.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(material)
pages = pdfReader.numPages
print(pages)
speaker = pyttsx3.init()
speaker.say("Amazing! I love Python because it can also talk!")
speaker.runAndWait()


There are two issues with your code: PyPDF2 has been deprecated in favor of pypdf (see https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/) and for the deprecation, just have a look at the migration guide: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/migration-1-to-2.html#classes
With the latest pypdf code, you probably want to use something like this:
from pypdf import PdfReader


reader = PdfReader('Object_Oriented_Programming_Python_Tutorial.pdf')
pages = reader.pages
print(len(pages))

